# Где хранить свойство программы?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

У меня есть приложение на NET Core 3 и мне необходимо сохранить некоторые параметры, слышал, что для этого можно использовать файл с раширением .settings, но в Core ничего подобного не нашел, можете подсказать, что необходимо использовать?

Comment: это называется конфигурацией. смотря для какого приложения конфиг хранить нужно, но в общем виде используется `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` (пакет NuGet). с остальным гугл в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно Вы имели в виду файл appsettings.json. Все настройки приложения содержатся в этом файле. Содержимое файла разбито на разделы(секции),   `"Название раздела"`, далее через `:` внутри фигурных скобок `{` `}` прописывается пара Ключ-Значение `"Ключ":"Значение"`. Например, здесь могут храниться строки подключения к базам данных.

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings":
 {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=BookListRazor;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
  }
}
```

Вот здесь, короткое [видео](https://youtu.be/r_-SYc59LqQ), где рассказывается о назначении и структуре этого файла.

Comment: Ваш ответ потеряет смысл сразу как ссылки перестанут работать. Поэтому здесь принято размещать хотя-бы минимально необходимую информацию прямо в посте.

Comment: исправил и дополнил ответ